# "Login As Another User" button while Login with Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am developing an application where I am integration the Login functionality of Facebook. The application runs successfully, but when I test with my Note 10.2, it also shows a "Login as another user" button at the end. While this behavior is not shown when testing on Note3 and other mobile devices.

This device does not have that button:
[image]

While this has it:

[image]

I tried to edit the facebook SDK and changed the WebDialog.java file and put a Scrollbar on the WebView that calls this url, but no success. Please help me with this problem

Thanks a lot in advance.